# C++17 why is there no default constructor provided when passing in arguments

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization

I have this class:

```
class MyClass {
public:
    int someMember;
    std::vector<int> someVectorMember;
};
```

and I was wondering why this wouldn't work:

```
MyClass(1, std::vector<int>{1,2});
```

Error:

```
main.cpp:21:37: error: no matching function for call to ‘MyClass::MyClass(int, std::vector)’
```

Comment: questions about a compiler error should incldue a [mcve] and the complete compiler error message in the quesiton

Comment: `PolygonDataRoomOrdering(...)` is calling a constructor (that doesnt exist), `PolygonDataRoomOrdering{...} ` is list initialization

Comment: what is the thought behind not providing a default constructor for the first example?

Comment: Your compiler is outdated or you didn't enable the latest C++ standard. This should work in C++20 or newer. You're not calling a custom constructor (or any constructor of `PolygonDataRoomOrdering` at all), you're doing aggregate initialization (individually initializing each struct field).

Comment: a default constructor is one that can be called without arguments. Your class has a compiler generated default constructor but  you are passing arguments

Comment: I see, thank you all for the answers!

Comment: I edited the question, hopefully, now it shows better what was actually confusing me.

Comment: Always post complete error along with your question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing two arguments of which the first is of type `int` and the second is of type `std::vector<int>` while there is no such constructor that takes two parameters of the mentioned types. Note also that in C++17, `MyClass` **aggregate initialization** cannot work using *parenthesis*.

---

In C++20 though **aggregate initialization** can use *parenthesis* so this will work in c++20 as per [p0960: Allow initializing aggregates from a parenthesized list of values](https://wg21.link/p0960)
.

---

> why is there no default constructor provided

There is a default ctor `MyClass::MyClass()` **implicitly generated** by the compiler, it's just that it cannot be used for `MyClass(1, std::vector<int>{1,2})`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have not defined any constructor that takes in an `int` and a `std::vector<int>`. If you do not define constructor, then there will be a default constructor generated, but that constructor does not have any parameters, as specified by the standard here https://eel.is/c++draft/class.default.ctor#1

Comment: What does this add to the already posted answer?